# Iron-router same route reload

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteorite

Here is my iron-router route

```
    this.route("video",{
      path:'/video/:_id/:slug',
       waitOn: function() {
         Session.set("currentTitle",this.params.slug);
         Session.set("currentVideoId",this.params._id);
         console.log("waitOn");
       },
      onBeforeAction: function () {
      },
      action:function(){
        console.log("action");
        this.render();
      },
      data:function(){
        console.log("data");
            var video= Videos.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
             if(video){
              console.log("set the url");
              Session.set("currentVideoURL",video.videourl);  
              Session.set("thumb",video.thumbs);  
            }            
            return {
              video:video
            };
      }
});
```

After the template rendered event I'm calling some meteor method and processing the result

```
Template.video.rendered=function(){
          console.log("render event");                 
        var id=Session.get("currentVideoURL");
        Meteor.call("getdata",id,function(e,d){
            //processing
        });
};
```

and in my html, I'm displaying some relative videos, on click of those videos I want to open the same page with this video data

but the video data in router is resetting and the rendered event is not firing(I didn't seen render event in console),

I want the page to open as we are coming from another url, I want all the events to be fired.

How to acheive this?

Comment: Maybe Template.renderWithData

Comment: how to use renderWithData in this context, I don't have much Idea, can you explain it?